# Listing attributes of namedtuple subclass

Tags: python, attributes, subclass, python-3.3, namedtuple

I have a tiny class that extends a `namedtuple`, but the `__dict__` property of its instances is always returning empty.

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
p1 = Point(20, 15)
print(p1, p1.__dict__)
# Point(x=20, y=15) OrderedDict([('x', 20), ('y', 15)]) <--- ok

class SubPoint(Point): pass
p2 = SubPoint(20, 15)
print(p2, p2.__dict__)
# SubPoint(x=20, y=15) {} <--- why is it empty?
```

`p2` has the attributes, but its `__dict__` is empty. They are listed correctly with `dir()`, though, which is strange. Note this work correctly when `SubPoint` extends a vanilla class.

What is happening, and how do I list the attributes in my subclass instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see why `__dict__` doesn't work, check the [answer by Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754054/12519962). This answer covers the second part of the question (how to list namedtuple attributes).

To list namedtuple attributes, there are [`_fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields) and [`_asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict):

```py
>>> import collections as c
>>> Point = c.namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y"])
>>> p1 = Point(20, 15)
>>> print(p1._fields)
('x', 'y')
>>> print(p1._asdict())
{'x': 20, 'y': 15}
>>> class SubPoint(Point): pass
...
>>> p2 = SubPoint(20, 15)
>>> print(p2._fields)
('x', 'y')
>>> print(p2._asdict())
{'x': 20, 'y': 15}
```

Note that `_fields` is defined on the class, so you can also do:

```py
>>> print(SubPoint._fields)
('x', 'y')
```

Obviously, `_asdict` needs an instance so it can use the values.

I used Python 3.9.7 for the examples, I'm not exactly sure when this stuff was added (maybe someone who knows can comment).

Comment: These existed back then as well, but the question was about a particular doubt not if something like this exists. :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks, I've edited the answer. I probably should have just added some info to your answer since it covers the first part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `__slots__` is only limited to a class it is defined in, so base classes will always have their own `__dict__` attribute unless you define `__slots__` there too. (And also note that the `__dict__` attribute of `namedtuple` is not a normal dict but a [@property](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l239).)

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots):

> The action of a `__slots__` declaration is limited to the class where it
>   is defined. As a result, subclasses will have a `__dict__` unless they
>   also define `__slots__` (which must only contain names of any additional
>   slots).

So, when you defined `__slots__` in the subclass then it failed to look for an attribute `__dict__` in that class, so moved on to base class where it found the `__dict__` attribute.

**A simple demo:**

```
class A:
    __slots__=  ('a', 'b')

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        print ('inside A')
        return self.__slots__         

class B(A):
    pass

print(B().__dict__)

print ('-'*20)

class B(A):
    __slots__ = ()
print(B().__dict__)
```

**output:**

```
{}
--------------------
inside A
()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(A.__annotations__.keys())
```

Comment: Please include an explanation for your answer.